# Flutter State management with Provider using multiple screens

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I have Two pages, `Page_A` and `Page_B` in my app. I have two other classes which update a `_votes` variable(default = 0) in my `Privider Class` then display this variable in `Page_A` and this works fine as espected.

I am trying to access this variable (`_votes`) which is now updated to say `23` in a new page `Page_B`. But when ever the new page gets Pushes unto the screen, it seems the variable gets reset to `0` instead of `23`. How can I achieve what am trying to do.

Comment: can you show what you've done so far?

Answer (score 5):

Let say this is your provider class

```
class AppState with ChangeNotifier {
  int _votes = 0;

  getVotes() => _votes;

  setVotes(votes) {
    _votes = votes;
    notifyListeners();
 }}
```

//to access

```
appState = Provider.of<AppState>(context);
```

//to get the current value

```
appState.getVotes();
```

//to set the value

```
v = 23;
appState.setVotes(v);
```

make sure the root class should look like this:

```
void main() {
   runApp(new MyApp());}


 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return ChangeNotifierProvider<AppState>(
         create: (_) => AppState(),
         child: MaterialApp(
           home: HomePage(),
           debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false));
      }
   }
```

Comment: replace "builder: (_) => AppState()" with "create: (_) => TodoProvider()". Builder is deprecated in recent versions of Provider library.

Comment: What if I want multiple page groups each to have their own provider model? How do   I wrap only specific screens of the app with ChangeNotifierProvider instead of wrapping the whole app?